# How to the refresh ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

ArrayList page that opens as a result page after update and save. I guess i would need to somehow refresh with invalidate() so that it reflects the changes on the UI. is it good way to refresh?

Comment: just type invalidate() where you want to update the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about `invalidate()`, but as far as I know when a ListView is updated you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh it and reflect changes on UI.